# How can I change Apollo Server WS path?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Is there any way to change path of Apollo Server WS (server.subscriptionsPath)?

Default path is '/graphql'. How can I set other route, e.g. 'ws://localhost:3000/api'?

```js
import express from 'express'
import http from 'http'
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express'

const app = express()

// ...

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
})

const httpServer = http.createServer(app)
server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer)

console.log('server.graphqlPath', server.graphqlPath)
console.log('server.subscriptionsPath', server.subscriptionsPath)

httpServer.listen({ port:300 })
```

Answer (score 5):

If anybody else is looking for an answer.  This worked for me:

```
// ...

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
})

// This is missing in your example
server.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  path: '/my-custom-path-here',
});

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include a `subscriptions` object in your `ApolloServer` config with the following properties:

> - path:
> - keepAlive:
> - onConnect:
> - onDisconnect:

`subscriptions` may also just be a string, in which case it's used just to define the path, or you can pass in `false` to disable subscriptions altogether.

See [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server) for all the configuration options.